# Unable to restore cloud sql backup

Tags: google-cloud-sql, gcloud

I followed this link to restore my backup
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/restoring

and i've tried restoring on multiple instances too

but in every instance's this error comes up in logs

Couldn't repair table: mysql.general_log
Failed to write to mysql.general_log: Incorrect key file for table 'general_log'; try to repair it

Answer (score 0):

First, address the error. Your general query log is enabled, but the install default is disabled. If you do not need the table enabled, then once everything is working, disable it.  I would suggest take a fresh [backup](https://n2ws.com/how-to-guides/mysql-database-backup-verification-recovery-aws.html) and then:

A. Repair the table using the `mysqlcheck -r YourDB general_log` command. (If this is an ISAM table use `myisamchk` instead.)

B. If that does not repair the table, first try `mysqlcheck -r YourDB` to repair the whole database (sometimes more than just the table needs to be repaired.)

C. If the restore still doesn't work than there are a couple of possibilities: the database may be corrupted or the backup file is corrupted. You don't mention any other errors, so I do not suspect the whole database is corrupted.

D. To check on the corrupted file, you can create a fresh database instance and try your restore there.  If that does not work you can try restoring a data table to confirm if the backup file is usable.

Be prepared for the possibility your backup file is corrupt.